# How to cope with bottleneck/throttling with (async) event emitter/listener?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, out-of-memory, listener, throttling

I have an event listener that listens to, say, JSON files being downloaded and writes them to the disk. Like this:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';

const apiClient = ...;
const job = apiClient.request(...); // job class implements EventEmitter

let i = 0;
job.on('responseReceived', async (response) => {
  await fs.writeFile(response, `${i++}.json`, 'latin1'); 
});
```

As you can see, the event listener is `async`; this is not a problem per se, as the download job does - semantically speaking - not need to wait for each file being written.

**This all works fine as long as the number of files to download is small or only a few downloads happen at a time**. However, in some cases (e.g., retrieving files from cache instead of actually downloading them), the throughput is very large and very fast. In that case, `writeFile` takes so long that the listener cannot "write away" the files fast enough and I get an `out of memory` error, quite logically.

So what to do about it? I had two ideas:

1. One approach would be that the listener should first store all `response`'s and then process them one by one as fast as he can. However, when storing the responses in memory, that would logically also run into `out of memory` problems, and storing them on the disk is what I actually want to do from the beginning.
2. Another approach would be to make `job` `await` the listener somehow before it proceeds with the next download. However, I see two problems with that: First, it would no longer be possible to use a (standard Node) `EventEmitter` then, right? Second, and more importantly, it would violate the general concept of event listeners in my view because those should conceptually only *observe* `job`, not *influence* it. For instance, one faulty event listeners that is awaited could halt the whole job forever otherwise.

So is there a solution to this problem, maybe a best practice? It reminds me somehow of backpressuring streams, but that would probably be just another formulation of the second idea (and I also would like to stick to the event listener pattern).

Comment: You better make your response smaller and use the option 1. That will lead to microservice later on and it's good to scale. Do not try to transfer big payload through http, the time transfer is already slow, not even the writing process. That's my opinion.

Comment: you can write into file using append option in fs.writeFile, so do not need to write all the payload to file at the same time